# c++ element of string array (chars) relies on source string

Tags: c++, string

A little context: I'm trying to make a very simple hashing function/hash table as [described here](http://www.cprogramming.com/codej/issue1.html#article2). I'm basically on the first step, blindly adding a key to an array based on the letter it starts with (no checking if space is occupied yet). The code I'm using to do this so far:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *arrayKeys[300];
    std::string aName("Charles");

    char *aNameCpy = new char[aName.size() + 1];
    std::copy(aName.begin(), aName.end(), aNameCpy);
    aNameCpy[aName.size()] = '\0';

    int kPos = storeKey(arrayKeys, aNameCpy);

    std::cout << "The new position in arrayKeys for 'Charles' is:  " <<
        kPos << "\ncontaining the text: " << arrayKeys[kPos] << std::endl;
    delete[] aNameCpy;  
    return 0;
}

int storeKey(char **keys, char *key) {

    int charLett = -1;
    charLett = (int)key[0];
    if(charLett != -1)
        charLett = charLett - 65;

    keys[charLett * 10] = key;

    return charLett*10;
}
```

My question is, how can I add a string to the array (arrayKeys) where it is fully apart of the array, and not reliant upon the original string? If I delete the copy of the string (aNamCpy) before I print the array key out, the array key turns into garbled symbols. I'm copying the string before sending it to the function because I need a non-const string to add to the arrayKeys array (so it can be modified), and any method of string I looked at seemed to return const.

(Another version of this I attempted can be [found here](http://truthandtar.com/display/hasht_tmp1.txt), but I would rather not initialize the arrayKeys like that - with a definite second dimension (string) length)
C++ is still very new to me so I can't figure out how to juggle the non-const part with copying the string into arrayKeys. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: A first attempt would be to not use char* in this case and just use std::string (and std::vector for the array)

Comment: Haven't used std::vector before but I'll look into, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd change the code to use more modern C++ constructs.  I think you'll find this way easier to use.

```
int storeKey(vector<string> &keys, const string &key) {
    int charLett = -1;

    if (!key.empty()) {  // you weren't doing this before!
        charLett = key[0];
        charLett = toupper(charLett) - 'A';
        keys[charLett * 10] = key;
    }

    return charLett*10;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> arrayKeys(300);
    std::string aName("Charles");

    // No need to bother with the awkward copying.
    // std::vector and std::string will take care of it for us.

    int kPos = storeKey(arrayKeys, aName);

    if (kPos >= 0) {
        cout << "The new position in arrayKeys for 'Charles' is:  " <<
            kPos << "\ncontaining the text: " << arrayKeys[kPos] << endl;
    }

    // Don't have to remember to delete anything because nothing was new'ed.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. Quick question, will I run into issues if I reuse the string aName? Or should I make a new one each time?

Comment: You'll overwrite that particular string object if you reassign it, but the elements in the vector will be safe.  They're all copies.

Answer (score 1):

(@Kristo has the right idea. I'm just going to add a comment to the question as asked.)

Basically, don't delete aNameCpy. You require the copy to remind valid and therefore it shouldn't be deleted. You should only delete the strings if and when you ever delete the entire hash.

> C++ is still very new to me so I can't figure out how to juggle the
>   non-const part

You could declare both `keys` and `key` to be `const char **keys`, `const char *key`. keys is pointer-to-pointer-to-char. More precisely, it's a pointer to *nonconst pointer* to *const char*. In other words, you can modify `keys`, you just cannot modify the actual characters it points (indirectly) at.

So, simply put `const` in your declaration of storeKey `int storeKey(const char **keys, const char *key)` and update arrayKeys accordingly `const char *arrayKeys[300];`

One final style issue: You should copy the string inside `storeKey`, not in main. This is better design, as it makes clear to the reader that storeKey "owns" the copy.

```
int storeKey(char **keys, const char *key) {
    char * the_copy = new char[strlen(key)+1];
    strcpy(the_copy, key);
```

... and so on

But, in short, use C++ `string` instead of all this, if you can!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I think I'm going to try the vector and strings method but that's all good to know anyways.